# How to load .xlsx file into external table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to load .xlsx file into external table, what are the formats I have to change in external table definition

tried with below code (it was .csv file) and I am getting data cartridge error

CREATE TABLE EXT_TEST
(
  COL1     NUMBER,
  COL2     NUMBER
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY DIR_TEST
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
    NOBADFILE
    LOGFILE 'test.log'
    NODISCARDFILE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    NOTRIM
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
   )
     LOCATION (DIR_TEST:'Book1.xlsx')
  )
REJECT LIMIT 0
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;

Comment: Save your .xlsx file's worksheet(s) as CSV files, and use those instead? Otherwise, as it's an XML format, you might be able to cobble somethign together with [XMLTAGS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle_loader-access-driver.html#GUID-04134666-4940-484E-BD7C-0E5BAF057DB9), or loading the whole file as a single XML document then parsing it. Neither sounds like much fun though...

Comment: I want to load in xlsx format only